# Is it necessary to use object store in python ray.serve?

Tags: python, ray

In python's ray.core, you can use an object store that can be shared by each Actor as follows.

```py
import numpy as np
import ray

@ray.remote
def Actor(a):
    return

a = np.zeros((5000, 5000))
result_ids = [Actor.remote(a) for x in range(10)]
results = ray.get(result_ids)
```

Is there any way to use object store in the same way in ray.serve if I have a large object like `np.zeros((5000, 5000))` ? (or do I need to use it?)

I tried the same description method as ray.core. However, self.obj remained as object id and could not be referenced as a remote.

```py
import ray
from ray import serve
from fastapi import FastAPI
import numpy as np

fast_app = FastAPI()

a = np.zeros((5000, 5000))
aid = ray.put(a)

@serve.deployment()
@serve.ingress(fast_app)
class Actor:
    def __init__(self,obj):
        self.obj = obj # <- not obj

    @fast_app.get("/obj")
    def health_check(self):
        return "test"

app = Actor.bind(aid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not

```
@serve.deployment()
@serve.ingress(fast_app)
class Actor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = ray.put(np.zeros((5000, 5000)))

    @fast_app.get("/obj")
    def health_check(self):
        return {"obj": ray.get(self.obj)}
```

Comment: Even with that writing method, obj becomes ObjectRef, so the data cannot be accessed. 

`ObjectRef(00b036c6bdbcec57f496a280b275def8f614f00a0100000001e1f505)`

```python
class Actor:
    def __init__(self):
        a = np.zeros((5000, 5000))
        aid = ay.put(a)
        print(aid) # ObjectRef(00b036c6bdbcec57f496a280b275def8f614f00a0100000001e1f505)
        self.obj = aid

```

Comment: If it remains as objectRef, for example, I don't think I can access the methods and properties provided for a in `a = np.zeros((5000, 5000))`, but is there a better way?

Comment: @user60150 It works fine in my ray serve: ray.get(self.obj) in def health_check.

Comment: @user60150 you couldn't use aid which is objectRef, this need ray.get

Comment: thank you! I should have used ray.get. It worked me too.